# Let G and H be simple graphs. Show $k$(GvH)= min {$v$(G)+$k$(H),$v$(H)+$k$(G)}

Tags: graph-theory

where $k$ is connectivity and v is the join operation.

This problem's got me really confused, I can't find any relation between the connectivity and the amount of vertices

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens when you delete vertices from $G \vee H$? If you still have vertices from both $G$ and $H$ remaining, is it possible that it is disconnected?

Comment: No, at least not that I can see

Comment: @Alan23 You should try to prove that it isn't possible for the graph to be disconnected without removing all of either $V(G)$ or $V(H)$. Then if you remove all of $V(G)$, you must remove an additional $\kappa(H)$ vertices to disconnect the graph, or if you remove all of $V(H)$, you must remove an additional $\kappa(G)$ vertices to disconnect the graph.